# Is this singleton hash map safe for multiple threads?

Tags: java

```
private Map<Integer, Data> _data = new HashMap<>();

public Data getData(final int id)
{
     return _data.getOrDefault(id, Data.EMPTY);
}

public static getInstance()
{
    return SingletonHolder._instance;
}

private static class SingletonHolder
{
    private static Holder _instance = new Holder();
}
```

This is for a game. Each attack, each spell casted from 2.500 players, each action will read from this class and from this map. There's no updating or removal, only reads.

Is this threadsafe? Is it correctly read-only?

Comment: where do you write to it?

Comment: What is `Holder`?

Comment: let's say values and data are written before server load and players log-in. So there is no way you can write or remove on it. Is it safe for read by 2.500 threads? Or i need make it ConcurrentHashMap?

Comment: you are safe, if you never write to it. data races can only happen when there is a _writer_ thread involved.

Comment: Provided you create a happens-before relationship between the writes to the map and the reads from the map, this can be thread-safe.

Comment: to be sure we do not give you the wrong advice - you _need_ to show the code that does the writing; otherwise all bets are off.

Comment: Holder is the name of the class, i gave random names i just want someone verify reading from HashMap by multiple players is safe. I dont want game crash. 2 days ago i had all values in a static way. I find HashMap more organized.

Comment: Ok guys, thank you very much so both Lists and Map don't need thread safety when it come in read only. I'll keep that in my mind. PS for List thread safe (for write i mean) what u suggest? CopyOnWriteArrayList ?

Comment: We see your [Initialization-on-demand holder idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom), but you're not using its result. Anyway, for it to be really correct, the `_instance` should also be `final`. If you do not need it to be lazily initialized upon first use, you can also simply use an enum with a single element. Regarding the map - we do not see the map's initialization, so we do not know. Show us where you're writing to the map, too. But if you publish it safely after writing to it, only reading from multiple threads is perfectly safe.

Comment: @TheLegendBeginsTremors no, it's more subtle than that: you need to ensure that the values written to the map are visible to all threads reading it. It's not sufficient to assume that "I'm not writing any more to the map, so it's ok": you have to actually create a happens-before.

Comment: `both Lists and Map don't need thread safety when it come in read only.`  This is false.  In fact this class is unlikely to be thread safe at all.  `_data` is not volatile or otherwise protected, so it could be seen as `null`.  Most of the commentors were asking for more context, you should listen to them rather than the few who said it was safe.

Comment: sorry mate - I am voting to close. whatever advice you implied from comments is wrong. SHOW the code, otherwise this will get closed, eventually.

Comment: Something else guys. Is safe to use getInstance() by multiple threads right? I mean i initialize the singleton while server load. After that i just call the object it should be thread safe right?

Comment: If you initialize the singleton while the server loads, there is no need for the lazy initializer. A straightforward static final field is simpler.